# Laravel Voyager Admin Panel Issue

Tags: laravel, voyager

Can anyone help? I am getting this error each time I want to install Voyager.
What can I do?
I have created a db and fixed my .env file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your users table already exists, Voyager comes with its own users table, if you dont currently have data in your users table, you can run `php artisan migrate:fresh` and remove your users migration before running the command.

Comment: I am still getting this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `translations` add unique `translations_table_name_column_n
ame_foreign_key_locale_unique`(`table_name`, `column_name`, `foreign_key`, `locale`))
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:18
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes")

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command `php artisan migrate -f`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.